# Is there a function in tensorflow for doing transformations that a functions of the indices?

Tags: python, tensorflow, differential-equations

I'm looking for (but have been completely unable to find) a function in tensorflow that will allow me to do a 'map' on a tensor.

**map**

Firstly, I'm not even sure if there is a 'map' function? By this a mean something that lets me apply a given f(x) to even entry in a tensor. e.g. I want something like this

```
def f(x):
  return x**2

Y = tf.Variable(np.array([[1.0, 2.0],
                          [3.0, 4.0]])

Y = tf.map_function(X, f)
```

producing (after suitably running in a session, obviously) a tensor with values

```
Y = [[1.0, 4.0],
     [9.0, 16.0]]
```

Does this exist (for general `f` - I realise that `tf.nn.relu` and `tf.nn.sigmoid? On one hand, it seems like it should, since`map` is a pretty fundamental operation. On the other hand, it would involve taking the supplied python function and somehow converting it to be executed on the GPU, and that sounds like something that might not be possible.

Am I asking for the moon on a stick here?

**mapi*

If such a function exists, is there a version that allows me to use an index-aware `f`? e.g.

```
def f(x, i):
  if (i != [0, 0]):
    k2 = np.sum([x**2 for x in i])
  else:
    k2 = 1.0 # To avoid division by zero
  return (x / k2)

Y = tf.Variable(np.ones(shape=(2,3)))

Y = tf.mapi_function(X, f)
```

producing

```
Y = [[1.0, 1.0, 0.25],
     [1.0, 0.5, 0.2]]
```

If such function don't exist, would it be possible (for fixed `f`) for me to add them by building tensorflow from (slightly modified) source?

**Why I need such a function**

The reason I'm asking this is that I'm trying to use tensorflow to numerically integrate a PDE. As part of that I need to compute the laplacian (d^2/dx^2 + d^2/dy^2 + d^2/dz^2) u(x,y,z). In a Fourier-transformed representation of the field u(k_X, k_y, k_z) this involves dividing by k_x^2 + k_y^2 + k_z^2.

I *could* precompute a tensor of inverse squared wavenumber values and dow an element-wise multiply. But this would use up a lot of memory. I suspect it would also be slower to load those values from memory.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific example of wanting to map individually to each of the `x,y,z` coordinates, you can accomplish this readily with `tf.split()` and `tf.stack()`.  That is, I presume you have an input tensor (call it `K`) that is of size `[n,m,...,3]`; that is, where the last dimension indexes the `x,y,z` coordinates.  If so, then use `tf.split()` to break up `K` into `Kx,Ky,Kz`.  Then apply your map operation (I use `tf.map_fn()` for this purpose typically), and then finally stack things back together with `tf.stack()`.

If I understand the setup correctly that should do it.  If not, please provide a minimal working example that will make the problem concrete; otherwise we are at best guessing at a solution.

Comment: Apologies, I think I have muddied the waters with my discussion of x,y,z components of a vector. Suppose I'm talking about a scalar field, u_dft, representing the DFT of some function u(x, y, z). Let's suppose I have 32 collocation points in each direction, so that
u.shape = [32, 32, 32]
and
u_dft.shape = [32, 32, 32]

See, what I want to do is divide each element u_dft[i, j, k] by (i^2 + j^2 + k^2). I can't split & stack because I'd be splitting 32 times, for each of the three dimensions! (I presume that would be as slow as doing it all in serial.)

Thanks for tf.map_fn though!